# I am not able to connect github using bamboo

Tags: bamboo

Installed latest version of bamboo. I am not able to pull the repository from the github. I am getting below error..

Bamboo Server Edition
Version : 6.9.0

I am getting below error

[Git credentials storage exception.])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at agent logs. It should contain more details. Usually it means Bamboo was not able to create or access credentials file.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboo documentation advises against installing Bamboo main directory into C:/Program Files
and also you may want to avoid installing "bamboo-home" into users directory.

I faced the same exception.  What worked for me was creating a new folder "X" on desktop and redirecting the Bamboo installation to folder "X."

Similarly, I did the same thing for "bamboo-home."

(Sorry, I don't have the link for bamboo documentation on this.  You may want to find it yourself.)